# Flutter Plugin Development native vendored_frameworks file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, webrtc, flutter-plugin, webrtc-ios

I'm working on the [flutter-webrtc](https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc) plugin for iOS. Previously, the plugin use the prebuilt cocoapods dependency. But, in the [WebRTC M80 Release Notes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/Ozvbd0p7Q1Y) they state they are going to be deprecating the mobile libraries.

To stay up to date with the latest iOS native WebRTC bugfixes and features, we now need to [build from source](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/docs/native-code/ios/index.md).

I've built from source and I was testing it with WebRTC's AppRTCMobile example app and it is working over there. Now I am trying to import the `WebRTC.framework` into the flutter plugin and I'm having trouble.

There is no flutter documentation on this, but I followed guidance from [this github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17978). I've copied the binary built from source into the [plugin ios directory](https://github.com/KernelLabs/flutter-webrtc/tree/tools/ios-webrtc-binary/ios/WebRTC.framework) and modified the [flutter_webrtc.podspec](https://github.com/KernelLabs/flutter-webrtc/blob/tools/ios-webrtc-binary/ios/flutter_webrtc.podspec) to include the framework, but I'm getting the error:

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/corey/Workspace/flutter/flutter-webrtc/ios/Classes/FlutterWebRTCPlugin.m:1:
    /Users/corey/Workspace/flutter/flutter-webrtc/ios/Classes/FlutterWebRTCPlugin.h:4:9: fatal error: 'WebRTC/RTCDataChannel.h' file not found
    #import <WebRTC/RTCDataChannel.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/corey/Workspace/flutter/flutter-webrtc/ios/Classes/FlutterRTCVideoRenderer.m:1:
    In file included from /Users/corey/Workspace/flutter/flutter-webrtc/ios/Classes/FlutterRTCVideoRenderer.h:1:
    /Users/corey/Workspace/flutter/flutter-webrtc/ios/Classes/FlutterWebRTCPlugin.h:4:9: fatal error: 'WebRTC/RTCDataChannel.h' file not found
    #import <WebRTC/RTCDataChannel.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

I'm really new to flutter plugin development so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. Any tips would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After adding the binary to the plugin ios directory, I needed to manually go into my app's ios directory (the app depending on the plugin) and manually run `pod install && pod update`.

After that, the plugin import errors were fixed and I'm now using WebRTC built from source in the flutter-webrtc plugin :)